# Git - choose which base to use in merge

Tags: git, merge

The merge I have to make has two merge bases somehow

```
kevins-mbp:TAMenuApp kevin$ git merge-base --all dev_build v3_merge
0c16efd68f4defa7bd39f092a631691ace269a9d
70f568259b4ccbb105d390ac93a8a4d721fe27ec
```

is there a way to cherry-pick which of these IDs to use as the base for the merge? I'm actually trying to use [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) which produces this error when trying to perform this merge:

```
kevins-mbp:TAMenuApp kevin$ git-imerge merge dev_build
u'v3_merge' and 'dev_build' do not have a unique merge base
```

so I was hoping to be able to specify which base to use.

Comment: Does vanilla `git merge` do this? According to the documentation for I think normal `git merge` can handle this case.  It sounds like an issue with `imerge`.

Comment: Yes; `git-merge-recursive` will build a blended merge base (that's the recursive part) while the less often used `git-merge-resolve` will just use the first parent.  Unfortunately, that has no effect on `git-imerge`.